# Confusion matrix error with less test data than training data

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, training-data, confusion-matrix

I have an issue with my model accuracy calculation. I used the code below:

```
y_train = [ 1  1  1  4  4  3  3  5 5 5 ]; % true labels for x_train
%x_test : has no true labels. 
predictedLabel=[ 1 2 3 4 5 ]; % predicted labels for x_test

group=y_train ; % 10
grouphat=predictedLabel; % for test 5 test data
C=confusionmat(group,grouphat);
Accuracy = sum ( diag (C)) / sum (C (:)) ×100;
```

but I get the error:

> Error using confusionmat (line 75)
>
> G and GHAT need to have same number of rows

Do I get this error since the test data is more or less than the train? There is no true label for test data (semi supervised learning).

Comment: What's unclear about the error? `confusionmat` expects the inputs to have the same number of rows, which you're not providing... without a [mcve] this is unanswerable

Comment: @wolfie, I understand. But i can not provide it, since the test data has no true labels and the labels for the test data are predicted from the algorithm. The group is labels ( true) for the train data which is 1000) and the group hat ( labels predicted for the test data and it is 500)

Comment: Do you have the actual labels for the dataset behind `predictedLabel`? I think that should be the `group` argument for `confusionmat`. The point of that function is to compare the actual labels to the predicted labels to see how they compare. There's no relation between the training labels and the predicted labels if they're not based on the same input points

Comment: maybe you are not using standard terminology, but AFAIK, in ML, "testing data" is data that should have labels, but you did not used in training. That way, you can "test" if your training was successfull in a new set of data, of which you know the expected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your training labels and predicted labels are based on different inputs, so it doesn't make sense to compare them in a confusion matrix. From the [`confusionmat` docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/confusionmat.html):

> returns the confusion matrix C determined by the **known and predicted groups**

i.e. the known and predicted results *for the same data*.

Take this partly pseudo-code example, see the comments for details

```
% split your input data
trainData = data(1:100, :);  % Training data
testData = data(101:120, :); % Testing data (mutually exclusive from training)
% Do some training (pseudo-code, not valid MATLAB)
% ** Let's assume that the labels are in column 1 **
model = train( trainData(:,1), trainData(:,2:end) );
% Test your model on the input data, excluding the actual labels in column 1
predictedLabels =  model( testData(:,2:end) );
% Get the actual labels from column 1
actualLabels = testData(:,1);
% Note that size(predictedLabels) == size(actualLabels)
% Now we can do a confusion matrix
C = confusionmat( actualLabels, predictedLabels )
```

Comment: The input data has two parts : 1. has true labels, 2. has no true labels.                                                           actualLabels = testData(:,1); i do not have it, the algorithm predict it ( semi supervised )

Comment: Then a confusion matrix isn't a relevant measure of anything for you. It is designed to compare your known results with predictions from the same data, you need to do what I've shown above and hold out some training data with known labels to use in your confusion matrix.